# Groovy File.eachFileRecurse deprecated

Tags: groovy

When trying to recursively list files in Groovy using the code snippet

```
new File("").eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES, { file ->
    list << file
})
```

IntelliJ is complaining that this is a deprecated method in DefaultGroovyMethods, which is correct.
The preferred way seems to be to use this method from ResourceGroovyMethods instead.
I was wondering why Groovy uses the deprecated version instead of the preferred version by default?

I am using the latest and greatest version of Groovy = 2.3.0

Comment: Which version of groovy are You using?

Comment: @Opal I edited the question to clarify the used version

Comment: Interestingly, DefaultGroovyMethods [reroutes to ResourceGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java)

Comment: What version of intellij? This is most likely a bug in that version. The methods got moved as DefaultGroovyMethods was becoming a bit of a monolith